# Cura: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Arcus'

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, python, dependencies, pacman

I installed cura on Arch linux using yay. It worked fine for some time but now when I try to run cura I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cura", line 23, in <module>
    import Arcus  # @UnusedImport
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Arcus'
```

When I try to install package called `Arcus`, it says it is allready installed.

WHat should I do run cura without this error ?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem in more general way was described and solved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621730/i-upgraded-my-system-now-a-lot-of-python-based-software-is-throwing-import-error).

This is the solution:

> Solution was to go to `/etc/pacman.conf` and uncommnet
>
> ```
> [testing]
> Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> [multilib-testing]
> Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
> ```
>
> Than run `sudo pacman -Syyuu`. It will take a while but at the end
> everything should be fixed.