# I upgraded my system now a lot of python based software is throwing import error

Tags: arch-linux, python, dependencies, pacman, python3

I upgraded my system using `yay -Syu` and some of programs and commands are throwing import errors when I try to run them.

For example:

**cura:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cura", line 24, in <module>
    import Savitar  # @UnusedImport
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Savitar'
```

**blueman:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/blueman-applet", line 15, in <module>
    from blueman.Functions import create_logger, create_parser, set_proc_title
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blueman'
```

**ranger:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ranger", line 35, in <module>
    import ranger  # NOQA pylint: disable=import-self,wrong-import-position
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ranger'
```

When I try to install these packages pacman and yay are saying there are installed.
How can I fix this?

Thank you for help. I am very nervous about this because it has huge impact on my work on collage related stuff. Thanks to everyone for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to go to `/etc/pacman.conf` and uncommnet

```
[testing]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

and

```
[multilib-testing]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

Than run `sudo pacman -Syyuu`. It will take a while but at the end everything should be fixed.

Comment: ....but *why* does your solution work? *What* does it do? *How* does it achieve it?